# Git requests to Azure Bot Service App in Azure Portal are failing, how do I troubleshoot?

Tags: git, azure, botframework

[image: Error after git attempt]

Hey,
I'm trying to update my bot application via git, but it keeps giving me this 500 error. How do I sort out this error? What logs should I be looking for?

Comment: There's currently an issue in the Bot Service that is being addressed, your problem might be related.  Are you able to see the kudo console when you navigate to [YourBotId].scm.azurewebsites.net ?

Comment: I get this exception: [IOException: The user name or password is incorrect.] on kudu

Comment: Your issue sounds similar.  A fix will be deployed soon.

Comment: I've been experiencing this issue since Monday, any update, @EricDahlvang?

Comment: I'm sorry this hasn't been resolved yet.  I have this stack overflow post in my list, and I will come back and update once a patch has been released.

Comment: We are also working on getting https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/ udpated for the Bot Service.

Comment: Saw your answer here, https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2580#issuecomment-293772933, @EricDahlvang, much thanks.  Will you post it here for me to close off this question?

Comment: Hey Irwin, I hadn't forgotten about this question.  I was just waiting to confirm that your issue is also resolved.  There are two parts to the release: one last night and one this morning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bots created in the past few days using the Azure Bot service are in a state that is difficult to recover from.  Re-connecting the existing bot to the correct storage account is a relatively complex operation, involving adding a WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE app setting that points to the correct storage account.

The issue itself has been fixed, so newly created bots will not experience the problem.  The easiest solution is to re-create the bot in the Azure Bot Service, and upload your code to that bot (and delete the bot with the problem).

We apologize for this inconvenience, and hope your future experiences with the Bot Framework are productive and enjoyable.