# Unable to push code to azure bot service

Tags: git, azure, botframework

I'm using Bot Service on Azure to deploy a simple bot. When i created, i choose to use my own git server, but added a remote to azure.
Now, im getting error 500 when tried to push and deploy new code.

The error i'm getting is

```
fatal: unable to access 'theazureurltoproject.git': The requested URL returned error: 500.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43350797/git-requests-to-azure-bot-service-app-in-azure-portal-are-failing-how-do-i-trou. Please see the coments

Comment: AzureSupport askme to post the quiestion to escalate to an engineer team

Comment: I will post this to azuresupport as aditional info

Comment: @dodoconr I'll report back here once the issue has been fixed, and verified.  Please remember that the Bot Service is currently in preview, and actively being developed.  Bots created with the SDK, and deployed to Azure, have not experienced these recent issues.

Comment: Would you please try downloading the Azure Storage Explorer?  See if your code is available there.  I've detailed how to find it within the storage explorer in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43268966/azure-bot-code-seems-to-be-erased#comment73827680_43268966

Comment: Hi eric, i can see the files. Can i deploy new code from here? The automated tasks will work?